# How to change a Generally formatted "20170824 08:45:58:544" into a Time formatted hh:mm:ss.ss?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, format, date-time

The title is the gist of my problem. I've got a couple of thousand of these I need to convert into a hh:mm:ss.ss format while retaining (though not showing) the yyyymmdd converted to a mm/dd/yyyy format.

So what would be in each new cell is a time formatted mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.ss, but only the hh:mm:ss.ss would be showing. Also the ss.ss for the example in the title would be "58.544"

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula to parse the text to a date format that Excel can recognize:

```
=--REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",".",3),7,0,"/"),5,0,"/")
```

It starts by replacing the last `:` with `.`.

Then it puts the `/` in the correct places.  The `--` forces Excel to convert the resulting text string to a number.

Then format the resulting number to `hh:mm:ss.000`

It will retain the date portion but only show the time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried this formula:

```
=TEXT(MID(A1,10,8)&"."&ROUND(MID(A1,19,9)/10,0),"hh:mm:ss.00")
```

As the format for your values are the same `yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss:000` you can use the formula to extract the time `hh:mm:ss` and change the `:` to `.` and extract the sunffix value.

At last use the `TEXT` function to format the value to `hh:mm:ss.00`.